# system call in read and write functions

Tags: c

I read textbook (Advanced Programming in Unix Environment)

> The functions described in this chapter are often referred to as unbuffered I/O, in contrast to the standard I/O routines, which we describe in Chapter 5. **The term unbuffered means that each read or write invokes a system call in the kernel.** These unbuffered I/O functions are not part of ISO C, but are part of POSIX.1 and the Single UNIX Speciﬁcation.

I am confused with **The term unbuffered means that each read or write invokes a system call in the kernel.**

read and write function is

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t nbytes);
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

I could not find anything special in their parameters, which parameter is system call?

Comment: `read` and `write` themselves are direct invocations of a system call. Not to be confused with `fread` and `fwrite`, which are standard IO routines.

Comment: oh, got it, unbuffered is to manually define BUFFSIZE. could you please transmit the comment to answer. @user58697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system calls are expensive, therefore the standard IO library postpones them as much as possible, e.g. by internally buffering the output. When it cannot buffer anymore, it finally invokes a system call.

This buffer is normally associated with the `FILE` pointer, so the rule of thumb is that the function taking `FILE *` does buffering, and the function taking the raw `int` file descriptor does a system call. It is just a convention, no more.

The Posix nomenclature tries to prefix the standard IO routines with `f`, such as `fwrite`, whereas the raw system call is `write` (same for `fopen` vs `open`, etc). There is noting special about parameters, it is in a name.

Comment: @Sawajiri As requested.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, those *are* the system calls. It's *conceivable* that they may just be a normal function that uses other system calls to do the work (for example, `read` calling an underlying set of smaller operations), UNIX and its brethren tend to map one-to-one.

But the basic idea with unbuffered I/O is that there is no caching going on.

When you read and write data in an unbuffered manner, the data is immediately sent to, or retrieved from, the underlying layers (the system calls alluded to).

Contrast that with a *buffered* approach where data can be cached before it's written, or more can be read than needed in the expectation it *will* be needed, both which can lead to more efficiency.

For example, see the following (pseudo-code) `writebuffered`:

```
def internal buffer size 1024 initially empty
def function writebuffered, accepts data:
    for each char in data:
        if internal buffer is full:
            write internal buffer
            empty internal buffer
        append char to internal buffer
```

You can see there that it will only make a system call (the `write`) when the internal buffer is full, resulting in less system calls overall. Obviously, you wouldn't process a character at a time in real life but the act of processing larger chunks would unnecessarily complicate the code. The intent here is just to show the buffering.

Likewise, when reading (for example, 27 characters), the system call may get a larger amount (say 1K) and save it in a readahead buffer for later, since you'll *likely* want to read more.

Then that later read, assuming it's for less than or equal to `1K - 27` bytes, won't have to make another system call to get data, it can just get it from the readahead buffer.

Comment: does `read` or write also take the buffer cache in the kernel or directly write to the disk?